# Filter map for values of None

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hashmap, filtering

I've searched around a bit, but haven't found a good answer yet on how to filter out any entries into a map that have a value of None. Say I have a map like this:

```
val map = Map[String, Option[Int]]("one" -> Some(1), 
                                   "two" -> Some(2), 
                                   "three" -> None)
```

I'd like to end up returning a map with just the `("one", Some(1))` and `("two", Some(2))` pair. I understand that this is done with flatten when you have a list, but I'm not sure how to achieve the effect on a map without splitting it up into keys and values, and then trying to rejoin them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Like every collection type in the scala.collection namespace a `Map` has the `filter` method defined and `Option`has the `isDefined` method, which is `true` for `Some` and `false` for `None`. You can filter out the `None`values by combining these two:

```
scala> map.filter(_._2.isDefined)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Option[Int]] = Map(one -> Some(1), two -> Some(2))
```

Comment: Neato. I wouldn't have guessed the syntax though. Still a little confused on `_.` From what I understand, we're telling it to go to the second item (the value) of the first (current) pair?

Comment: @KChaloux In this case `_` refers to the first argument of a function literal being passed to the `filter` method. It's a shorthand for `x => x._2.isDefined`

Comment: And the _2 comes from the [Tuple](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2).

Answer (score 58):

If you're filtering out `None` values, you might as well extract the `Some` values at the same time to end up with a `Map[String,Int]`:

```
scala> map.collect { case (key, Some(value)) => (key, value) }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2)
```

Answer (score 7):

Also
`map.filterKeys( map(_) != None)`

or

`for( (k,v) <- map if( v!= None)) yield (k,v)`

This approach provides a general filterValues method that doesn't exist on maps.
I miss such a method, because none of the alternatives is perfect.

[Updated later]   This is a better version that doesn't do a lookup on each entry and still reads reasonably clearly.

`map.filter( {case (x,y)=> y!=None})`